# I am trying to add flutter blue in my pubspec.yaml file, but version solving is failed

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I am trying to add flutter blue in my `pubspec.yaml` file, but version solving is failed but it does not seem to support existence with flutter reactive ble in the same pubspec.yaml file.

The following is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker:
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0
  equatable: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  intl: ^0.16.1
  auto_orientation: 2.1.0
  exif: ^1.0.2
  image: ^2.1.4
  flutter_exif_rotation: 0.3.0
  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
  ffi: ^1.0.0
  provider: ^4.0.5
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  get: ^4.6.1
  flutter_reactive_ble: ^3.1.1+1
  js: ^0.6.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

In the terminal, when I run,

```
flutter pub add flutter_blue
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Because flutter_blue <0.4.0 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0 and flutter_blue >=0.4.0 <0
.4.2 depends on protobuf ^0.9.1, flutter_blue <0.4.2 requires protobuf ^0.9.1.
And because flutter_blue >=0.4.2 <0.6.0 depends on protobuf ^0.10.5, flutter_blue <0.6.0 re
quires protobuf ^0.9.1 or ^0.10.5.
And because flutter_blue >=0.6.0 <0.6.1 depends on protobuf ^0.13.12 and flutter_blue >=0.6
.1 <0.6.3+1 depends on protobuf ^0.14.1, flutter_blue <0.6.3+1 requires protobuf ^0.9.1 or
^0.10.5 or ^0.13.12 or ^0.14.1.
And because flutter_blue >=0.6.3+1 <0.7.2 depends on protobuf ^1.0.0 and flutter_blue ^0.7.
2 depends on protobuf ^1.0.1, flutter_blue <0.8.0 requires protobuf ^0.9.1 or ^0.10.5 or ^0
.13.12 or ^0.14.1 or >=1.0.0 <2.0.0.
And because flutter_reactive_ble ^3.0.0 depends on protobuf ^2.0.0 and flutter_blue >=0.8.0
 depends on convert ^3.0.0, if flutter_reactive_ble ^3.0.0 and flutter_blue any then conver
t ^3.0.0.
And because attendanceapp depends on exif ^1.0.2 which depends on convert ^2.0.0, flutter_r
eactive_ble ^3.0.0 is incompatible with flutter_blue.
So, because attendanceapp depends on both flutter_reactive_ble ^3.1.1+1 and flutter_blue an
y, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Now if the change to A SDK version, as stated, I am getting so many other errors. All dependencies match this project except the flutter blue.

The project completely works fine without the addition of flutter blue.

If I upgrade the packages, I still cannot match the flutter blue with my other dependencies I am using.

I scratching my head and I don't know which flutter blue versions I should be using.

Please assist me someone.

Comment: Could you please specify which version of flutter sdk you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `flutter_blue` to `0.7.0` and `flutter_reactive_ble` to `2.7.3`. I am not sure that so old versions contain all the features you need. But `pug get` shows no errors with this set of versions

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker:
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0
  equatable: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  intl: ^0.16.1
  auto_orientation: 2.1.0
  exif: ^1.0.2
  image: ^2.1.4
  flutter_exif_rotation: 0.3.0
  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
  ffi: ^1.0.0
  provider: ^4.0.5
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  get: ^4.6.1
  flutter_reactive_ble: 2.7.3
  js: ^0.6.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  flutter_blue: 0.7.0
```

[image]